# Can I configure pairing for HC-05 and Arduino, and use the HC-05 without Arduino after?

Tags: bluetooth, communication, electronics, hc-05

I have a system that is outputting data via its serial, and I need to relay that data to my PC wireless-ly. If I were to setup an Arduino and HC-05 at the system's side to relay the data, that would mean I need to use two serial ports. I know this could be done with SoftwareSerial library. However, I would like to know if I could set up the pairing between master and slave with arduino, then unplug the HC-05 from the Arduino, and connect it directly to the system's serial output. Would this work?

Edit for clarification:

- I do not want to use SoftwareSerial
- I do not want to use an MCU during normal operations
- I want the HC-05 to take in serial data from a system's serial, and transmit it via bluetooth to my PC
- Only during pairing configuration, will I want use an MCU (Arduino) to set it up. I want to know if the comms will still work when I take out the Arduino and connect the system's serial data output to HC-05's Rx instead.

Is this possible?

Comment: configure the HC-05 and pair it, then power it down .... power up again and run a sketch like the one in this question and test connectivity with serial monitor .......  https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/61469/does-baud-rate-for-hc-05-bluetooth-module-need-to-match-the-serial-monitor/61510#61510

Comment: I haven't built anything yet, I am just going through design planning before building it. Preferrably, I do not want to use SoftwareSerial. My idea is to pair it up with Arduino, and get the HC-05 to trasmit whatever serial data that comes into its Rx from the system - without an Arduino in place.

Comment: i understand your requirements .... the comment describes a process for confirming that the HC-05 retains its settings when powered off

Comment: IIRC, you can pull up (or leave unconnected) the KEY pin of the HC-05. Then it will act as the transparent serial connection you want.